# Xamarin forms IOS sirikit intent extension donating intent is not supported by this application

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am currently having an issue with using SiriKit for my xamarin forms project but I am unable to find out what is missing or not correctly linked. I am unable to post up my code but I will give a description of what I have done till this point.

Firstly, in order to create a custom intent, I followed the instructions in this link and created my custom intent using xcode and the static library using sharpie 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/introduction-to-ios12/siri-shortcuts

Then, in my xamarin forms project, I created an App.Intent.Bindings project, an App.Intent.Extension project, an App.Intent.ExtensionUI project, and an App.Intent.Shared project.

The static library generated and Xamarin.iOs is referenced by App.Intent.Bindings project. The generated APIDefinitions and StructsAndEnums file are also placed under the App.Intent.Bindings project file.

The App.Intent.Extension project contains an IntentHandler file and has reference to App.Intent.Bindings, App.Intent.Shared and Xamarin.iOS.

The App.Intent.ExtensionUI project has a reference to Xamarin.iOS and contains the file IntentViewController.

The App.Intent.Shared Project contains the  intents.Intentdefinition file, custom intent handler file and custom intent object file and has a reference to App.Intent.Bindings and Xamarin.iOS.

All Entitlement files have a field which specified the common shared app group.

The info.plist file of the App.Intent.Extension project has the custom intent listed under the IntentsSupported key.

An NSExtensionPointIdentifier key with a value of com.apple.intents-service and NSExtensionPrincipalClass key with a value of IntentHandler. All Projects created which has the entitlements.plist file has Siri Enabled.

On AppStore, the provisioning profile for all the different projects have Siri Permissions as well as App group permissions.

However, currently I am getting an logged error which says that donating intent is not supported by this application, please ensure that you declare the intents that your app supports by including the NSUserActivityTypes Key in its Info.plist or your app contains an Intents extension that supports this intent.

Also, whenever I try to trigger this custom intent that I created, I was told to continue in my application instead when it was supposed to run in the background. Note that I did follow the instructions during custom intent creation to check the allow background execution checkbox.

I have checked many if not all the forums with similar error messages and tried the answers suggested but to no avail. Would any kind soul out there be kind enough to advise me on what else I could possibly have missed out and what else I could try to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you got solution?